# Inkscape: SVG to PDF removes groups

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, adobe-illustrator, inkscape

I've made a SVG generator using SVG.js, which creates over 100 Path elements, all of them placed in 6 different groups. The resulting SVG file opened with Adobe Illustrator shows the groups ok.

However, I'm using Inkscape in command-line (required for automation process) to convert the SVG file to PDF.

```
 inkscape --file=input.svg --export-area-drawing --without-gui --export-pdf=output.pdf
```

The PDF file is generated with all its Path elements on the same level, without any kind of groups/layers, which is mandatory for my project.

Is there a way Inkscape does not ungroup the elements?

Attached an image of the final result (left side, SVG file - right side, the converted PDF)

[Image: SVG and PDF layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct02t.png)

Example SVG:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 95 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="5">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="15" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="25" r="15" />
    <circle cx="55" cy="25" r="15" />
    <circle cx="70" cy="25" r="15" />
</g>
<g stroke="red" fill="white" stroke-width="5">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="15" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="25" r="15" />
    <circle cx="55" cy="25" r="15" />
    <circle cx="70" cy="25" r="15" />
</g>
```

Comment: My Inkscape v0.92.1 seems to export to PDF 1.4 as a default, which does not support layers. The GUI export dialog shows the option to export to PDF 1.5. Have you tried `--export-pdf-version=1.5`?

Comment: Right now I'm using v0.92.2. I have also tried using `--export-pdf-version=1.5` but it didn't change anything

Comment: AFAIK, this is impossible since Inkscape does not support an option equivalent to "Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities".  With this option unchecked AI exports all the artwork to a single group in PDF